# Django Swagger Schema: Object of type Boolean is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, core-api, django-swagger

I am working on a custom schema and got an error saying `Object of type Boolean is not JSON serializable` on the Swagger documentation page.

```py
import coreapi
import coreschema
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema


class CustomSchema(AutoSchema):
    def get_manual_fields(self, path, method):
        manual_fields = []
        if method == "POST":
            manual_fields.extend(
                [
                    coreapi.Field(
                        "custom_field",
                        required=False,
                        location="form",
                        description="custom field",
                        type=coreschema.Boolean()
                    )
                ]
            )
        return manual_fields
```

I noticed that using `location="query"` would not yield the error above, but I need it in the `form` for Swagger. Is there any workaround? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily solving the error above, but here's a workaround that worked for the same purpose:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import CustomModel


class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_field = serializers.BooleanField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

Rather than calling `schema = CustomSchema()` from the `views`, Call this `CustomSerializer` and specify a `write_only` field in the serializer automatically populates the Swagger schema for the POST method.